# add label next to input text form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i just want make some added text next to my input.

im using code igniter, here is my view code.

```
<div class="form-group" >
                    <label for="repbbpin" class="col-sm-2 text-left">Tinggi Badan :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5 text-left">
                        <span ><input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="update_data()" name="tinggi_badan"  value="<?=@$registration->tinggi_badan?>" > cm</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the top code result "cm" is below the input text.

it will be  good if just using additional inline code.

the result i want is like this  |---input text---|cm

Comment: what do you mean? you want a label show the input-text when user input something?

Comment: Sounds like css here

Comment: the result i want is like this : |---input text---|cm.
yes, but i would be nice if there is add some code inline the div

Comment: try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ozqe1fzk/1/) 
but if you set the value it will ignore the placeholder

Comment: @Max , still doesn't work. cm still on below position. if i set that inline that should've override the css right ?

Comment: You may consider using input-group and input-group-addon https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/crvzn2Lq/

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen thank you very much. you are the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using input-addon with input-group

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="repbbpin" class="col-sm-2 text-left">Tinggi Badan :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5 text-left">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="update_data()" name="tinggi_badan" placeHolder="input text" ><span class="input-group-addon"> cm</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/crvzn2Lq/